# Can't seem to multiply the hard way

Tags: c++, dynamic

I'm attempting to make a class that holds a (in theory) infinite amount of digits using c-strings, since ints have a limit. I am having a lot of trouble with multiplication and have begun to confuse myself. I am a student, so any help and mistakes I have not caught are very appreciated. I've been playing around with just the multiplication for 4 hours now.

The current problem is that I am calculating the results right (like if you try x = 12 and y = 4, I will only get 8 from it, then the final answer becomes 7 which is odd) but it isn't storing properly.

definition:

```
MyInt operator* (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y)
{
  MyInt steps[x.numDigits - 1]; // Create an array of MyInts

  int carry = 0;           // Holds the 'carry the one' 
  int result, xInt, yInt;  // For adding old-school


  // Add each digit separately.
  for (int i = 0; i < x.numDigits; i++)
  {
    steps[i].numDigits = y.numDigits;     // set the numDigits to y's

    // Resize the array to the size of numDigits
    steps[i].Resize(steps[i].numDigits);

    cout << "x.numDigits = " << x.numDigits << '\n';     // DELETE THESE
    cout << "numDigits = " << steps[i].numDigits << '\n';

    // Figure out xInt's value
    xInt = C2I(x.myNumber[x.numDigits - i - 1]);

    // Now multiply xInt by each digit of y
    for (int j = 1; j <= y.numDigits; j++)
    {
      // yInt's value for this run through
      yInt = C2I(y.myNumber[y.numDigits - j]);

      // Answer is xInt * yInt + the remainder
      result = ((xInt * yInt) + carry);
      carry = 0;               // Reset carry to zero

      // If the result is 10 or higher,  carry the excess
      if (result > 9)
      {
    carry = result / 10;
    result = result % 10;
      }

      // Assign result to the appropriate slot in the new number
      steps[i].myNumber[(steps[i].numDigits - j)] = I2C(result);

      cout << "ASSIGNED " << steps[i].myNumber[steps[i].numDigits - j] //DELETE THESE 
       << " TO SLOT " << (steps[i].numDigits - j)
       << " with a rem = " << carry << '\n';
    }
    cout << "YOU GOT OUT OF THE J FOR LOOP\n";
    // If carry wasn't reset to 0, that means the loop ended.
    // This means there is a # that cannot fit in the current
    // array size. We must resize, and then assign
    // the extra characters into the array.
    if (carry > 0)
    {
      int carryCopy = carry; // Copy of n for counting numDigits
      int carryCount = 0;    // Counts up how many digits are in carry

      while(carryCopy > 0)   // Figure out how many #'s there are
      {
    carryCopy = carryCopy / 10;
    carryCount++;
      }

      // Figure out the new size
      steps[i].numDigits = steps[i].numDigits + carryCount;

      // Resize to new size
      steps[i].Resize(steps[i].numDigits + carryCount);

      // Copy in the new digits
      for (int k = carryCount-1; k >= 0; k--)
      {
    steps[i].myNumber[k] = I2C(carry % 10);
    carry = carry / 10;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "What you have so far is " << steps[0] << "\n"; // DELETE
  cout << "YOU GOT TO THE ADDING PART\n";                 // DELETE

  MyInt r = 0; // Create MyInt for total result

  // Add up all of the arrays in steps[] into r 
  for (int l = 0; l < x.numDigits - 1; l++)
    r = r + steps[l];

  return r;                   // Result
}
```

Header file

```
#include <iostream>// for ostream, istream
using namespace std;

class MyInt
{
   // these overload starters are declared as friend functions

   friend MyInt operator+ (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
   friend MyInt operator* (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);

   friend bool operator< (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
   friend bool operator> (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
   friend bool operator<= (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
   friend bool operator>= (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
   friend bool operator== (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);
   friend bool operator!= (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y);

   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, const MyInt& n);
   friend istream& operator>> (istream& s, MyInt& n);

public:
   MyInt(int n = 0);        // first constructor
   MyInt(const char * n);       // second constructor
   ~MyInt();                    // Destructor

   MyInt(const MyInt & n);      // Copy Constructor
   MyInt& operator= (const MyInt & n); // Assignment operator

   // be sure to add in the second constructor, and the user-defined 
   //  versions of destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator

private:

   // member data (suggested:  use a dynamic array to store the digits)
   unsigned int numDigits;  // The number of digits in myInt
   char * myNumber;             // Pointer to dynamic array of digits
   void Resize(unsigned int newSize); // Resize array
};
```

and the main program I am using to test:

```
int main()
{
  // demonstrate behavior of the two constructors and the << overload

  MyInt x(12345), y("9876543210123456789"), r1(-1000), r2 = "14H67", r3;
  char answer;
  cout << "Initial values: \nx = " << x << "\ny = " << y
       << "\nr1 = " << r1 << "\nr2 = " << r2 << "\nr3 = " << r3 << "\n\n";

  // demonstrate >> overload

  cout << "Enter first number: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Enter second number: ";
  cin >> y;

  cout << "You entered:\n";
  cout << "  x = " << x << '\n';
  cout << "  y = " << y << '\n';

  // demonstrate assignment =
  cout << "Assigning r1 = y ...\n";
  r1 = y;
  cout << "  r1 = " << r1 << '\n';

  // demonstrate comparison overloads
  if (x < y)    cout << "(x < y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x > y)    cout << "(x > y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x <= y)   cout << "(x <= y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x >= y)   cout << "(x >= y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x == y)   cout << "(x == y) is TRUE\n";
  if (x != y)   cout << "(x != y) is TRUE\n";

  // demonstrating + and * overloads
  r1 = x + y;
  cout << "The sum (x + y) = " << r1 << '\n';
  r2 = x * y;
  cout << "The product (x * y) = " << r2 << "\n\n";
  cout << "The sum (x + 12345) = " << x + 12345 << '\n';
  cout << "The product (y * 98765) = " << y * 98765 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Go back through your code and insert comments that explain exactly what each line is doing, and why.  Specify, at various points, what values are contained in what variables.  By the time you're done you'll likely have discovered 3-4 errors.

Comment: Your reckless use of `new` and raw pointers will indubitably make the whole thing explode at some point. Why not use an existing standard library component for dynamic memory management?

Comment: As I said, I am a student so I dont know any other way to do this other than the above commands. What'd you suggest?

Comment: @jordaninternets: I'd start with a `std::vector<char>` or something like that to hold the digits. You're using base-256, I assume?

Comment: I would say he is using base 10, a std::vector<char> would be better but given this is a homework there might be constraints on what is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing all the multiplication first, then the adding. This is inefficient and makes your code more complicated.

Instead, you should add the results together as you compute each multiply stage.

For example, instead of:

```
A = 123
B = 456
S[0] = A * (B[2] * 10^2) = 123 * 400 = 49200
S[1] = A * (B[1] * 10^1) = 123 * 50 = 6150
S[2] = A * (B[0] * 10^0) = 123 * 6 = 738
R = S[0] + S[1] + S[2] = 49200 + 6150 + 738 = 56088
```

do this:

```
A = 123
B = 456
R = 0
R += A * (B[2] * 10^2) = 0 + 123 * 400 = 49200
R += A * (B[1] * 10^1) = 49200 + 123 * 50 = 55350
R += A * (B[0] * 10^0) = 55350 + 123 * 6 = 56088
```

This gets rid of the need for the `steps` array (`S` in my example).

Also, consider storing the digits in your array least-significant-digit first. This allows you to replace the `* 10^N` steps with index shifts.

```
A = 123
B = 456
R = 0
R[0:] += A * B[0] = 123 * 6 = 738()
R[1:] += A * B[1] = 123 * 5 + 73 = 688(8)
R[2:] += A * B[2] = 123 * 4 + 68 = 560(88)
```

Where the `()` part is the digits shifted past by the indexing of `R`. This technique also makes it easier to add or remove most-significant-digits since they're at the end of the array and not the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for the long response, but after rewriting I finally got it to work! Another key for beginners that I learned in the process is to separate a lot into different functions. That way, it doesn't get so confusing so fast. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, that's a big step: learning what needs to get separated into functions. For the record, the GNU `gmp` library does optimized arbitrary precision math. `gcc` uses it, so if you have `gcc`, you probably have `gmp`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is that `steps` is initialized with a size of `x.numDigits - 1` but your for loops goes past the end of the array. Perhaps you meant this `steps` should be of size `x.numDigits`. There may be other bugs than just this.

Comment: There for sure are :[
Thank you, though

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Did you fix this bug?

Comment: I fixed this bug, but I was saying yes to your comment about there being other bugs. This is not the big one.